# Redirecting multiple URLS with parameters via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've seen plenty of answers here about this question but none seem to help me.

I have a list of about 300 URLs that all have parameters in them. I want to redirect each one to different URLs on a new domain. The thing is, the redirection is determined by the content of the page, not param name = page name or something of the sort.
So, I have a list of old page = new page, how would I create something like that in htaccess?
If there were no parameters I would do:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page-name/ http://newurl.com/new-page-name
```

however that doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Edit:
I tried this and it doesn't work. Possibly this would be easier for anyone to help out with?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} muflaim\.co\.il [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/classic?page=shop.product_details&category_id=&flypage=flypage_experience.tpl&product_id=200$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.dreambox.co.il/45217/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: What do you mean the content of the page?

Comment: I mean it has nothing to do with code. I decided based on what the page contains, where I want each page to redirect to.
I don't need a solution for all URLs together, rather a one by one solution

Comment: I just edited the Q, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this helpful, this did the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} muflaim\.co\.il [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop.product_details&category_id=&flypage=flypage_experience.tpl&product_id=200$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^shop/classic$ http://www.dreambox.co.il/45217? [R=301,L,NC]
```